# VBS- Login script to map drive with multiple NICs

Tags: authentication, vbscript, drive-mapping

I am trying to create a script to map drive at logon as per IP address or subnet. I was able to find one script which works well on single MIC, but thre are few machines who have 2 Nics, and it does not work with them.

Here is modified script.

```
set objNetwork = CreateObject("Wscript.Network")
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set colAdapters = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select * From Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration Where IPEnabled=True")


ReDim arrSubnets(-1)
For Each objAdapter in colAdapters
  For Each strAddress in objAdapter.IPAddress
    arrOctets = Split(strAddress, ".")
    If arrOctets(0) <> "" Then
      ReDim Preserve arrSubnets(UBound(arrSubnets)+1)
      arrSubnets(UBound(arrSubnets)) = arrOctets(0) & "." & arrOctets(1) & "." _
        & arrOctets(2)

    End If
  Next
Next

    Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery _ 
        ("Select * From Win32_LogicalDisk Where DeviceID = 'G:'") 
If colItems.Count = 0 Then


    strSubnet = arrSubnets(UBound(arrSubnets))
 Select Case strSubnet


       Case "10.1.1" 
            objNetwork.MapNetworkDrive "G:", "\\10.1.1.62\zShared",True
        objNetwork.MapNetworkDrive "F:", "\\10.1.1.62\zShared2",True

        Case "10.1.20" 
            objNetwork.MapNetworkDrive "G:", "\\10.1.20.150\sharedch",True
        objNetwork.MapNetworkDrive "F:", "\\10.1.20.150\sharedch1",True 
End Select

End If
```

Comment: Umm... *which* error?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply.

I am getting error below.

Line : 14
Char : 14
Error : Type Mismatch : 'arrsubnets'
Code : 800A000D

Comment: https://skydrive.live.com/?mkt=en-US#cid=415FBD1F15F38083&id=415FBD1F15F38083%21201&v=3

Answer (score 1):

You use `arrSubnets` without initializing (or resizing) it. Also, you're trying to echo `arrSubnetIPs(i)` when you should be echoing `arrSubnets(i)`. Change this:

```
i = 0

For Each objAdapter in colAdapters
  For Each strAddress in objAdapter.IPAddress
    arrOctets = Split(strAddress, ".")
    If arrOctets(0) <> "" Then
      arrSubnets(i) = arrOctets(0) & "." & arrOctets(1) & "." & arrOctets(2)
      i = i + 1
      WScript.Echo arrSubnetIPs(i)
    End If
  Next
Next
```

into this:

```
ReDim arrSubnets(-1)
For Each objAdapter in colAdapters
  For Each strAddress in objAdapter.IPAddress
    arrOctets = Split(strAddress, ".")
    If arrOctets(0) <> "" Then
      ReDim Preserve arrSubnets(UBound(arrSubnets)+1)
      arrSubnets(UBound(arrSubnets)) = arrOctets(0) & "." & arrOctets(1) & "." _
        & arrOctets(2)
      WScript.Echo arrSubnets(UBound(arrSubnets))
    End If
  Next
Next
```

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for your reply, but now i am getting some other error.
Here is script i use this time.

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for your reply, but now i am getting some other error.
Here is script i use this time.

Per Echoing I was doing it just for debugging the issue, i dont ned to echo subnetwork.
Here is url for error.
https://skydrive.live.com/?mkt=en-US#cid=415FBD1F15F38083&id=415FBD1F15F38083%21202&v=3
 
Here script url.
https://skydrive.live.com/?mkt=en-US#cid=415FBD1F15F38083&id=415FBD1F15F38083%21203

Comment: @user2744072 Please edit your question and add the modified script or post it someplace where it can be viewed without having to enable JavaScript.

Comment: Hi,

Sorry for inconvenience.
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1YrgJw5JruqtFZlkMKUFNn5Hx1eFPMmq2VVBvNhusA4U/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: docs.google.com requires JavaScript as well. Why can't you just update your question?

Comment: Edited and posted latest modified script.

Comment: `If colItems1.Count = 0 Then`: you assign the results of the WMI query to a variable `colItems`, but use an (undefined) variable `colItems1` in the conditional. And you're using the (still undefined) `arrSubnetIPs`. Why did you add that to the second half of the script after you fixed it in the first half? Please change every occurrence of `arrSubnetIPs` to `arrSubnets` and add `Option Explicit` at the beginning of the script. If that doesn't help, post the exact error message (error number, description and line number) you're getting.

Comment: Hi, I updated the script,  error details.

Line 16, Char 7, Error: Subscript Out of Range:[Number:1]
Code: 800A0009

Comment: What is the value of `UBound(arrOctets)` (or the value of `strAddress`) in that iteration? Try changing the check `If arrOctets(0) <> "" Then` to `If UBound(arrOctets) > 1 Then`.

Comment: WOW, Thanks it looks working on my test environment let me test it on production and update you....

Thanks alot.

Comment: If that helped, your host probably had an IPv6 address.

Comment: Hi, It helped, actually i want to understand how this code for getting subnetwork is working.
Now some conditions are changed at our environment, we just need to check first two octet of IP and then map drive accordingly.

Comment: I get this much after removing this code " & "." _ & arrOctets(2)" from the script it will give me first two octets.
But i am still wondering what is use of "_" in this code {" & "." _ & arrOctets(2)" }

Comment: Normally VBScript statements must be on one line. `_` indicates a line-continuation (vulgo a wrapped line), i.e. the current statement is continued in the next line.